# Extension method, Func of T and List of T

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, extension-methods

I would like to code a function that can accomplish some check before insert a value into a List.
For example:

```
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
-------
var persons = new List<Person>();
// add a new person if John doesn't exist
persons.AddIf(s => !s.Name.Equals("John"), new Person { ... });
----
public static void AddIf(this List<T> lst, Func<T, bool> check, T data)
{
     // how can I use the Func 'check' to check if exist an object with the
     // information that the client wrote and, if not exists, insert the new value
     // into the list???
     if ( check )
}
```

How can I use the Func 'check' to check if exist an object with the information that the client wrote and, if not exists, insert the new value into the list?

Comment: Note that in your example, you create the Person object regardless of the predicate result. If you do not intend to use this object if the check fails, you should probably change the signature of the method so that the Person object is created only if needed.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis most probably its just a dummy variable OP put there. He might very well have an instance to add already..

Answer (score 11):

You need to make your method generic.

```
public static void AddIf<T>(this List<T> lst, Func<T, bool> check, T data)
{
    if (!lst.All(check))
        return;

    lst.Add(data);
}
```

And usage like you wanted (all items should satisfy predicate):

```
persons.AddIf(s => !s.Name.Equals("John"), new Person { ... });
```

Comment: For generalization, i would use Expression<Func<T,bool>>. And semantic of method is bad. You add if not a condition.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov agreed and removed. BTW what benefit expression tree will give here?

Comment: `All` will fail, if any does not satisfy predicate (i.e. its name is John), and we do not add new person.

Comment: ok... so I need to check my data through the condition... Why use Expression ??

Comment: @lazyberezovsky ya so shouldn't it be if `if(lst.Any(check)) return;`?

Comment: @nawfal in this case I should verify for `s => s.Name.Equals("John")`. But we are passing predicate `s => !s.Name.Equals("John")`, so all should not satisfy it.

Comment: @Gaetanu you shouldn't use expression here.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky oh yes I missed that `!` part in OP's question

Comment: Benefit of expression is use it for IQueriable too. Generalization.

Answer (score 0):

For your own semantics you have an answer already to rely on. But to me the method naming is obfuscatory the more I think of it. `AddIf` means add if any or add if all? In your case it is all. So you should be naming it better. `AddIfAll` or something.

To add to a list if something doesn't exist is a common requirement and what I would suggest is something little more fleshed out (I believe) for your purpose which makes it easier from the caller side.

May be

```
public static bool AddIfNotContains<S, T>(this ICollection<S> lstObject, 
                                          Func<S, T> selector, T valueToMatch,
                                          S objectToAdd)
{
    if (lstObject.Contains(selector, valueToMatch))
        return false;

    lstObject.Add(objectToAdd);
    return true;
}
```

A small `Contains` overload I prefer to use in my programs:

```
public static bool Contains<S, T>(this IEnumerable<S> lstObject, 
                                  Func<S, T> comparer, T valueToMatch)
{
    return lstObject.Any(s => comparer(s).Equals(valueToMatch));
}
```

This avoids the hassle of writing the `Equals` operator from our side every time.

You can call:

```
persons.AddIfNotContains(s => s.Name, "John", new Person { ... });
```

I think that makes the syntax much simpler.

### Note:

I hope you're aware of the catch here. You can very well write

```
persons.AddIfNotContains(s => s.Name, "John", new Person { Name = "Serena", .. });
```

**even when there exists already someone with the name `Serena`** because here you're checking for `John`. If that's ok for you, well and good. **A better implementation if I understand your problem correctly would be**:

```
public static bool AddIfTrulyNotContains<S, T>(this ICollection<S> lstObject, 
                                               Func<S, T> selector, S objectToAdd)
{
    if (lstObject.Contains(selector, selector(objectToAdd)))
        return false;

    lstObject.Add(objectToAdd);
    return true;
}
```

Now you can call easily:

```
persons.AddIfTrulyNotContains(s => s.Name, new Person { Name = "John", .. });
```

This just checks for `John` and adds if there's no `John` in list. Additionally I have made return type to `bool` to denote addition.

Answer (score 0):

quick combination/change from above answers, with some comments: (my rep is too low to simply comment *blush*)

So, based on certain details in the question's example:

> How can I use the Func 'check' to check if exist an object with the
>   information that the client wrote and, if not exists, insert the new
>   value into the list?

1) I would definitely consider creating/using a generic extension specifically for checking for duplicates (as mentioned, a common operation) before adding to list (rather than open "check"), so could be something like this:

```
public static void AddIfDistinct<T>(this List<T> lst, T data, Func<T, bool> dupeCheck)
{
    if (lst.Any(dupeCheck))
        return;

    lst.Add(data);
}
```

2) based on the requirement, "Any" is much clearer, semantically, than "All", in my opinion - we are checking for "any" duplicates, rather than checking that "all" current items are "not" duplicated... It might sound trivial, but I think its safe to say it is more immediately apparent. This obviously means the lambda you pass in would look like this (the change in semantics here mean you really have to get the extension method named well)

```
s => s.Name.Equals("John")
```

3) last comment, if its appropriate, you could also override some stuff on your class like "CompareTo" etc and create a really generic "AddToListIfUnique" etc

Also, using Expression< Func<...>> in your example would not help at all (as somebody suggested), as you're using List anyway (would only be worthwhile if you were using IQueryable etc)

Comment: Even if the name could false lead. The `IEnumerable.All()` method won't go through the whole list. It aborts immediately when the given func returns false. It's simply the exact opposite of `IEnumerable.Any()` which immediately returns when the given func returns true. So writing `if(!lst.Any(func))` iterates over as many items as `if(lst.All(func))`. Take a look at the remarks section at MSDN for [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) and [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

Comment: yes, 100% correct, amateur confusion there. I would still argue very strongly for it, however, as it is a much clearer indication of what is trying to be achieved. Will edit to reflect this...thanks.